# Not eating chametz in Eretz Yisrael on "Achron shel Pesach"

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover, eretz-yisrael, chametz-leaven, chabad

I heard that there is a letter from [the Rebbe Rashab (Chabad)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sholom_Dovber_Schneersohn) that one shouldn't eat chametz on Achron Shel Pesach when they are in Eretz Yisrael (even if they are keeping only one-day Yom Tov.) I understood perhaps it was directed specifically towards someone that was really from Chutz L'Aretz and was keeping one-day Yom Tov for whatever reason.

Has anyone seen or heard of such a letter? What's the source for this?

(I heard this originally b'shem a big Talmud Chacham that has a connection to Chabad, however I was never able to ask him where the makor is.)

Comment: FWIW, I've seen Lubavitchers eating chometz then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the fall of 1911 (early 5572), Rabbi Shalom DovBer of Lubavitch sent Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Havlin along with seven students to establish the "Torat Emet" yeshiva in Hebron, Israel.

Before Pesach that year, among their correspondences, the Rebbe Rashab advised Rabbi Havlin regarding how he and the original students should conduct themselves with the Pesach laws. With regard to Chametz, the students, whom intended to return to Europe, were instructed to behave as if they were currently in Europe. As for Rabbi Havlin, whose residency was as of yet undecided, he was instructed to pray the weekday prayers and wear Tefilin on Acharon shel Pesach as one who lives in Israel permanently would, but as for Chametz he was instructed to be scrupulous, due to the indecisiveness of the matter.

The original letter can be found in [אגרות קודש מוהרש"ב](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31691&st=&pgnum=232&hilite=).

Comment: If he wouldn't be doing malacha as well then it would seem pashut that he shouldn't be eaten chometz...Is the point of malacha not mentioned?

Comment: It's not mentioned.